# Telegram Bot: в базу данных mysql ( Ubuntu-16.04-x86_64 ) не записывается русский текст, но английский без проблем!

Tags: python, mysql, sql, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Использую VDS сервер VDS-OVZ-Разминка от 
FirstVDS на операционной системе Ubuntu-16.04-x86_64 (командная строка). Залил туда своего телеграмм бота и базу данных MySQL. Бот работает, но до того момента когда я пытаюсь записать в БД русский текст полученный от пользователя функцией message.text. Вы дает ошибку: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 33-39: ordinal not in range(128)` с английским текстом проблем нет!

Comment: А кодировки смотрели?

Comment: Это сообщение об ошибке питона, так что БД тут пока не причем. смотрите строку которая выдает ошибку, откуда она получает данные, что с ними делает. Вбитое в гугл сообщение об ошибке дает несколько интересных статей

Comment: Кодировка в БД utf8_general_ci ( мне нужна кодировка с поддержкой смайлов и русского текста, не подскажите какая именно? )


Если я к примеру ввиду слово картина, то в БД пытается впихнуть '\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u043d\u0430', а если слово picture, то все нормально.